# Убрать обратную связь related_name

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm, django-model

Мне нужно убрать не нужную связь `related_name` для оптимизации, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо присвоить `related_name='+'`, когда создаёте связи типа `ForeignKey` или `ManyToManyField`

Comment: Спасибо большое